# How to export from a blender file the .obj and .mtl file with texture

Tags: export, obj

I am new to blender. Here is my need.

I downloaded nice 3D models, e.g., from [here](https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/study-desk-3d-model-1207569). It includes a .blend file and the Texture file in jpg.

When I open the .blend file, I can see the object with texture. **What I need is that I want to save it to .obj and .mtl files with the texture.**

Here is what I did (I'm using blender 3.2.2)

1. Hit File -> Export -> Wavefront (.obj).
2. Select OBJ Objects and Material Groups.
3. Set Path Mode from "Auto" to "Copy".
4. Set Forward to X-axis and Up to Z-axis (this is just for my need).

Then I export to a folder, where I see a .obj and a .mtl file. But if I open the .obj file in a new blender file, I cannot see the texture. In particular, the .mtl file does not have map_Kd nor a path to the texture.

Here is what I tried:
I tried to manually modify the .mtl file by setting "map_Kd PATH_TO_TEXTURE." Now, if I open the blender and import the .obj file, I can see the color but still no texture.

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Same here. Looking for an answer.